# How to extract contents from PCollection in Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Just want to know how to extract things from PCollection?
Say I have applied a Count.Globally so there's a single number in the resulting PCollection, but how can I extract it as a Long value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want to use that value.

If you want to read that value after your pipeline finishes you could use one of the write transforms (e.g. [AvroIO.Write](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/AvroIO.Write)) to write it to some output that you could then read from whatever code executes after your pipeline finishes.

If you want to use that value in a subsequent part of your pipeline then you could apply a [View](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/View) transfrom to generate a PCollectionView which you could then pass as a side input to other transforms.

Consider a simple example where the goal is to print out the Count. The Count won't be available until after the pipeline runs. So in this case we could do the following

- Define a DoFn<Long, String> which we apply to the count in order to turn the Long into the message we want to print out.
- Apply a TextIO.Write transform to write the message to a file.
- Run the job and wait for it to finish. If we want to execute using the Dataflow Service we can use [BlockingDataflowRunner](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner) to wait for the job to finish.
- After the job finishes read the text file created to get the message and print it out.

Comment: I think I want to get a Long value and use inside the program. Say used in a if statement.

Comment: I've added an example, does this answer your question? The important thing is that a PCollection isn't materialized until the pipeline runs. So you need to run the pipeline in order to access the value. Pipelines can also (depending on the runner) run asynchronously and independently of your main program.

Comment: Jeremy, is there really no direct way to get access to the count, even supposing we already ran the pipeline? It seems really indirect to write it to disk then read it back in.

Comment: You can materialize it in your pipeline but not your main program. Your main program is constructing a graph of transformations. If you're executing that graph on the Dataflow service then the computations are actually executed on different machines than the one your main program is running on. So in order for your main program to read data, you need to use an IO transform to write it someplace accessible from your main program (e.g. a File/BigQuery/Datastore/Pubsub). However, if you want to read it in a later transform, Dataflow will pass the value for you.

Answer (score 1):

You must always think of `PCollection` as of a *stream*. The fact, that you applied a transform that creates single value *per window* does not guarantee there is really only single value. This depends on the windowing strategy - so there might  be single value in the case you use GlobalWindow, but there will be many values for other types of window functions (e.g. sliding windows).

Therefore it is not possible to extract this single value directly (e.g. something like `PCollection.get()`) - the return value would have to be a stream. If you want to retrieve result from a PCollection, you must apply to it a transform, that will store it somewhere. There is a rich set of build-in IO modules (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/)). If you want to retrieve the resulting value(s), and use it in a program later, the best option would be to store it in some shared database of your choice and retrieve this value after your Pipeline finishes. Note that this means your Pipeline is *bounded* (e.g. batch, not streaming), as otherwise it will never finish. But your question suggests that a bounded Pipeline is what you have in mind.