# Beam/Dataflow 2.2.0 - extract first n elements from pcollection

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Is there any way to extract first n elements in a beam pcollection? The documentation doesn't seem to indicate any such function. I think such an operation would require first a global element number assignment and then a filter - would be nice to have this functionality.

I use `Google DataFlow Java SDK 2.2.0`.

Comment: What is your use case for such an operation? Perhaps do you need the top N elements by some criterion? (the Top transform) Or do you need *any* N elements? (the Sample transform)

Comment: + please specify whether you use Java or Python SDK

Comment: yes, Top does serve the purpose. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCollection's are unordered per se, so the notion of "first N elements" does not exist - however:

- In case you need the top N elements by some criterion, you can use [the Top transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Top.html).
- In case you need *any* N elements, you can use [Sample](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Sample.html).

Comment: what if I have to extract the single element from PCollection returned by Max/Min Tranforms?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" then? The collection already has a single element (per window).

Comment: Extract means converting the Pcollection of single element to corresponding integer or long. Let say, I have a PCollection of Integers, and I need to find the MAX, then I can apply MAX Transform. But in that case, I will get a output as Pcollection of Integers having only single element which is the Max Integer. I want to convert that PCollection into Integer to extract the max value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668686/how-to-retrieve-the-content-of-a-pcollection-and-assign-it-to-a-normal-variable or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015924/how-to-extract-contents-from-pcollection-in-cloud-dataflow - this is not possible directly, by design, but there are workarounds.