# How to retrieve the content of a PCollection and assign it to a normal variable?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am using Apache-Beam with the Python SDK.

Currently, my pipeline reads multiple files, parse them and generate pandas dataframes from its data.
Then, it groups them into a *single* dataframe.

What I want now is to retrieve this single fat dataframe, assigning it to a normal Python variable.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You cannot get result back to a variable directly and if you don't want save the result to a file or database, you can use Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PCollection` is simply a logical node in the execution graph and its contents are not necessarily actually stored anywhere, so this is not possible directly.

However, you can ask your pipeline to write the `PCollection` to a file (e.g. convert elements to strings and use `WriteToText` with `num_shards=1`), run the pipeline and wait for it to finish, and then read that file from your main program.